# Javascript link to not exist directory

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I want to use my javascript file that is in `/js` directory but I cannot do it.

My file is at `htdocs\ElasticSearch\js` but the html file points the file to `htdocs\ElasticSearch\js\src\main\scripts` which doesn't exist

[image: my screen shot]

my HTML file here
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd7AB.png)

I want the HTML file to link to `htdocs\ElasticSearch\js`

Comment: what path you have provided in your code. It might point some where else that might be the reason for this error

Comment: Please post relevant snippets from your HTML here.